# Access violation error while running wireless simulation in omnet++ 6

Tags: omnet++

I have created LTE network(ned file and ini file) using simu 5G. Everything was fine but when I run simulation error shown as below.Please help

> Exception code=0xc0000005 flags=0x0 at 0x00007FFACAC121DB. Access violation - attempting to read data at address 0x0000000000000000
>
> Simulation terminated with exit code: c0000005
> Working directory: C:/omnetpp-6.0-windows-x86_64/omnetpp-6.0/myproject/first
> Command line: first.exe -m -n .;../simu5g/emulation;../simu5g/simulations;../simu5g/src;../inet4.5/examples;../inet4.5/showcases;../inet4.5/src;../inet4.5/tests/validation;../inet4.5/tests/networks;../inet4.5/tutorials -x simu5g.simulations.LTE.cars;simu5g.simulations.NR.cars;simu5g.nodes.cars;inet.common.selfdoc;inet.linklayer.configurator.gatescheduling.z3;inet.emulation;inet.showcases.visualizer.osg;inet.examples.emulation;inet.showcases.emulation;inet.transportlayer.tcp_lwip;inet.applications.voipstream;inet.visualizer.osg;inet.examples.voipstream --image-path=../simu5g/images;../inet4.5/images -l ../simu5g/src/simu5g -l ../inet4.5/src/INET lte.ini
>
> Environment variables:
> PATH=;C:/omnetpp-6.0-windows-x86_64/omnetpp-6.0/myproject/simu5g/src;C:/omnetpp-6.0-windows-x86_64/omnetpp-6.0/myproject/inet4.5/src;C:\omnetpp-6.0-windows-x86_64\omnetpp-6.0\bin;C:\omnetpp-6.0-windows-x86_64\omnetpp-6.0\tools\win32.x86_64\opt\mingw64\bin;C:\omnetpp-6.0-windows-x86_64\omnetpp-6.0\tools\win32.x86_64\usr\bin;C:\omnetpp-6.0-windows-x86_64\omnetpp-6.0\tools\win32.x86_64\mingw64\bin;;C:/omnetpp-6.0-windows-x86_64/omnetpp-6.0/ide//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.stripped.win32.x86_64_17.0.1.v20211116-1657/jre/bin/server;C:/omnetpp-6.0-windows-x86_64/omnetpp-6.0/ide//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.stripped.win32.x86_64_17.0.1.v20211116-1657/jre/bin;C:\omnetpp-6.0-windows-x86_64\omnetpp-6.0\bin;C:\omnetpp-6.0-windows-x86_64\omnetpp-6.0\tools\win32.x86_64\opt\mingw64\bin;C:\omnetpp-6.0-windows-x86_64\omnetpp-6.0\tools\win32.x86_64\mingw64\bin;C:\omnetpp-6.0-windows-x86_64\omnetpp-6.0\tools\win32.x86_64\usr\local\bin;C:\omnetpp-6.0-windows-x86_64\omnetpp-6.0\tools\win32.x86_64\usr\bin;C:\omnetpp-6.0-windows-x86_64\omnetpp-6.0\tools\win32.x86_64\usr\bin;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\omnetpp-6.0-windows-x86_64\omnetpp-6.0\tools\win32.x86_64\usr\bin\site_perl;C:\omnetpp-6.0-windows-x86_64\omnetpp-6.0\tools\win32.x86_64\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\omnetpp-6.0-windows-x86_64\omnetpp-6.0\tools\win32.x86_64\usr\bin\core_perl;C:\omnetpp-6.0-windows-x86_64\omnetpp-6.0;
> OMNETPP_RELEASE=omnetpp-6.0
> OMNETPP_IMAGE_PATH=C:\omnetpp-6.0-windows-x86_64\omnetpp-6.0\images

i was trying to run simulation to collect LTE data.

Answer (score 0):

To determine what part of code generates this exception, you may set in `omnetpp.ini`:

> debug-on-error = true

Then build the project in debug mode, and start debugging it. Debugger will stop just before the line which occurs an error. 
Reference: [OMNeT++ TicToc Tutorial - Debugging](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part2/#23-debugging)